# fetching multiple values from a string using regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table temp that have a column name "REMARKS"

Create script

```
Create table temp (id number,remarks varchar2(2000));
```

Insert script

```
Insert into temp values (1,'NAME =GAURAV Amount=981 Phone_number =98932324 Active Flag =Y');
Insert into temp values (2,'NAME =ROHAN Amount=984 Phone_number =98932333  Active Flag =N');
```

Now , i want to fetch the corresponding value of NAME ,Amount ,phone_number, active_flag from the remarks column of the table.

I thought of using regular expression ,but i am not comfortable in using it .
I tried with substr and instr to fetch the name from the remakrs column ,but if i want to fetch all four, i need to write a pl sql .Can we achieve this using Regular expression.

Can i get output(CURSOR) like

```
id  Name    Amount phone_number Active flag
------------------------------------------
1  Gaurav   981    98932324     Y
2  Rohan    984    98932333     N
-------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like :

```
SQL> select regexp_replace(remarks, '.*NAME *=([^ ]*).*', '\1') name,
  2         regexp_replace(remarks, '.*Amount *=([^ ]*).*', '\1') amount,
  3         regexp_replace(remarks, '.*Phone_number *=([^ ]*).*', '\1') ph_number,
  4         regexp_replace(remarks, '.*Active Flag *=([^ ]*).*', '\1') flag
  5    from temp;

NAME                 AMOUNT               PH_NUMBER            FLAG
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
GAURAV               981                  98932324             Y
ROHAN                981                  98932324             N
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution ,your faster than my expectation